# Windows installers for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-installer

I've recently built a Software project in Java. And now its time I build the installer package for the software. I've tried windows installer 4.5, but it couldn't even install on my pc. The operating system I'm using is Windows 8 pro. Is there an installer built by microsoft that can run on windows 8 x86? I know about advanced installer 10.2, but i'm still way too young, i can't afford it. I need a freeware installer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Advanced Installer has a free edition too, the "Simple" project type, which you can use for as long as you want, even for a Java application. The only limitation is that you don't have access to our Java launcher from the licensed editions, but you can make your own and include it as a normal file in the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 comes with Windows Installer 5.0.  You can't install 4.5.  Also Windows Installer isn't a windows platform service, not an installation authoring tool.

You can author Windows Installer databases (.MSI)  using a variety of tools including Windows Installer XML (WiX) (FOSS) and InstallShield Limited Edition (FREE).

Comment: Nice! How do i Locate the windows installer on my windows 8 PC, so that i can use it to build my project's installer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NSIS** (Nullsoft Install System) or **Inno Setup**. Both are free (even open-source).